# Display values of an array of object without using ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

In MongoDB I have the following the document.

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "58402903734d1d19c9a34cdd"
},
"deliveryComp": "abc",
"poorDel": 0,
"okDel": 1,
"wellDel": 0,
"veryWellDel": 1
}
```

When I call this data from mongodb using an angular controller it is being returned as an array, like so:

```
[{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "58402903734d1d19c9a34cdd"
},
"deliveryComp": "abc",
"poorDel": 0,
"okDel": 1,
"wellDel": 0,
"veryWellDel": 1
}]
```

I want to display the values but I don't want to use `ng-repeat`. Each value needs to be displayed in different parts of the app. There is no "repeating" data.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you know which entry you want to display at which position?

Comment: What's the size of the array?

Comment: Extract each object into its own variable and then link that to the element on the site? (Hope I understood what you wanted)

Comment: Why can't you use ng-repeat?

Comment: @Karthik the size of the array is 1. Exactly the same as shown in the question. It will always have only one object. I didn't save it as an array in the database. But its being returned as an array.

Comment: @Fonzy yes i know exactly which entry goes where.

Comment: use `data[0]` to get the value and assign to the scope in your controller. Then you can use the scope object in your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've only got 1 value in the array, you can use;

```
{{mongoDbData[0]._id.$oid}}
```

For every value in your array, use 0 because it's the first item in your array.

Answer (score 0):

If not mistaken, the issue seems to be that the document object you were expecting in wrapped as the only element of an array. In your controller, do as follows:

```
// assuming document to be the array-wrapped response
$scope.documentData = document[0];
```

so that in your view you can use data binding on `documentData`

```
<span>{{ documentData._id.$oid }}</span>
```

This will remove the need to always fetch the first element of the array in your data binding expression.